# AzureML ParallelRunStep runs only on one node

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I have an inference pipeline with some PythonScriptStep with a ParallelRunStep in the middle. Everything works fine except for the fact that all mini batches are run on one node during the ParallelRunStep, no matter how many nodes I put in the `node_count` config argument.

All the nodes seem to be up and running in the cluster, and according to the logs the `init()` function has been run on them multiple times. Diving into the logs I can see in **sys/error/10.0.0.*** that all the workers except the one that is working are saying:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/virtualstage/azureml/c36eb050-adc9-4c34-8a33-5f6d42dcb19c/wd/tmp8_txakpm/bg.png'`

**bg.png** happens to be a side argument created in a previous PythonScriptStep that I'm passing to the ParallelRunStep:

```py
bg_file = PipelineData('bg',  datastore=data_store)
bg_file_ds = bg_file.as_dataset()
bg_file_named = bg_file_ds.as_named_input("bg")
bg_file_dw = bg_file_named.as_download()

...

parallelrun_step = ParallelRunStep(
    name='batch-inference',
    parallel_run_config=parallel_run_config,
    inputs=[frames_data_named.as_download()],
    arguments=["--bg_folder", bg_file_dw],
    side_inputs=[bg_file_dw],
    output=inference_frames_ds,
    allow_reuse=True
)
```

What's happening here? Why the side argument seems to be available only in one worker while it fails in the others?

BTW I found [this](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/issues/957) similar but unresolved question.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you need to specify a local mount path to use side_inputs in more than one node:

```py
bg_file_named = bg_file_ds.as_named_input(f"bg")
bg_file_mnt = bg_file_named.as_mount(f"/tmp/{str(uuid.uuid4())}")

...

parallelrun_step = ParallelRunStep(
    name='batch-inference',
    parallel_run_config=parallel_run_config,
    inputs=[frames_data_named.as_download()],
    arguments=["--bg_folder", bg_file_mnt],
    side_inputs=[bg_file_mnt],
    output=inference_frames_ds,
    allow_reuse=True
)
```

Sources:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-debug-parallel-run-step
- https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/18355